# Does (∀x(r → p)) ∧ (∀x(p → q)) imply ∀x(r → q)?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

So the frustrating thing is that I am asked to decide whether the first implies the second, but I was given no deduction rules for predicate logic except the fact that $ ∀x(r(x) → p(x)) $ implies $ ∀x(r(x)) → ∀x(p(x)) $.

I came to the conclusion that, maybe I could reason on a meta-level. What I mean is that, if  $ (∀x(r(x) → p(x))) ∧ (∀x(p(x) → q(x))) $ does imply $ ∀x(r(x) → q(x))$, then I would have to show it for possibly an infinite number of variables $x$. But to show that $ (∀x(r(x) → p(x))) ∧ (∀x(p(x) → q(x))) $ doesn't imply $ ∀x(r(x) → q(x))$, I would only need to find one counter example. Since I was not given enough deduction rules, there is no way I could show it is true for all $x$, so my guess then is that the first does not imply the second and I'm assuming the book wants me to find a counter example.

However, I looked at the truth table for $ (r → p) ∧ (p → q) $ and this does imply $ r → q $. So which is right? Was my meta-reasoning incorrect, or is it possible that an implication in propositional logic may not have the same implication for the analogous statement in predicate logic?

Comment: I'm not even sure what "except the fact that ∀ distributes over →." means. Does it mean that $\forall x. (r \to p)$ allows one to conclude that $ (\forall x. r) \to (\forall x. p)$?

Comment: @John Hughes Yes. Should I edit the question to make it more clear?

Comment: I had a hard time believing it meant that because, as Bram28 points out, that's a false form of deduction (at least for ordinary logic).

Comment: @pmac Are you sure you weren't told that $(\forall x.P(x)\land Q(x))\iff (\forall x.P(x))\land(\forall x.Q(x))$? The formula I just stated is actually valid and pretty quickly leads to a proof (given rules for propositional logic).

Comment: @DerekElkins Yes I am sure. We were not given the formula you mention. The book is Numbers, Groups, and Codes by Humphreys and Prest. Do you mean we could just write  ∀x((r(x)→p(x)) ∧ (p(x)→q(x))) and treat the predicates as propositions? I did not think that was valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'll assume that $p$, $q$, and $r$ are formulas that contain $x$ as a free variable. Because if not, then these statements are simply equivalent to $r \to p$, $p \to q$, and $r \to q$, and obviously the first two imply the third.

So, let's write these statements as $\forall x ( r(x) \to p(x))$, $\forall x ( p(x) \to q(x))$, and $\forall x ( r(x) \to q(x))$ respectively.

Now, $\forall x ( r(x) \to p(x))$ is *not* equivalent to $\forall x\ r(x) \to \forall x \ p(x)$. For example, take as the domain all real numbers, let $r(x)$ be '$x$ is a rational number', and $p(x)$ be '$x$ is a prime number'. Then $\forall x\ r(x)$ is obviously false, and hence $\forall x\ r(x) \to \forall x \ p(x)$ is true, but $\forall x ( r(x) \to p(x))$ is false.

OK, but do $\forall x ( r(x) \to p(x))$ and $\forall x ( p(x) \to q(x))$ imply$\forall x ( r(x) \to q(x))$?  Intuitively, yes, of course: the first premise states that every '$r$' is a '$p$', and the second that every '$p$' is a '$q$'. So, if you take any '$r$', then by the first permise that has to be a '$p$', and by the second premise, it therefore has to be a '$q$'. Hence, every '$r$' is a '$q$', which is exactly what the conclusion is saying. So, this is a valid inference.

Comment: I have made some changes to the post for clarification. I did not mean that they were equivalent, but that ∀x(r(x)→p(x)) implies ∀x(r(x))→∀x(p(x)).

Comment: Ok. I guess your answer is how the book wanted me to do it anyways, since it says 'decide whether ∀x(r(x)→p(x))  and ∀x(p(x)→q(x)) implies ∀x(r(x)→q(x))', not 'prove whether...'

Comment: @pmac Ah, right, you indeed not say equivalent, my bad. And yes, $\forall (r(x) \to p(x))$ *does* imply $\forall x \ r(x) \to \forall x \ p(x))$. But, that still isn't going to help you, since that means that the two premises can be combined to imply $\forall x \ r(x) \to \forall x \ q(x)$ ... from which you cannot infer $\forall x (r(x) \to q(x))$

Comment: Maybe, given no useful deduction rules, we could go back to Aristotle's list of valid syllogisms. I believe this one was called (somewhat later, for mnemonic purposes) Barbara.